# Chef - Query a YUM Repo beforepkg install

Tags: ruby, regex, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I would like to query he YUM repo before I call the install block to make sure the pkg is available

I am using the following code at the beginning of my recipee

```
ruby_block 'shellout' do
  block do
    cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new('yum search httpd | grep -w httpd.x86_64 |tr -d "\n\r"'
    cmd.run_command
    Chef::Log.warn("printing #{cmd.stdout}")
    if cmd.stdout =~ /httpd/i
      Chef::Log.warn("pkg found in yum  #{cmd.stdout}")
    elsif cmd.stdout =~ /error/i
      Chef::Log.warn("yum returned an error #{cmd.stdout}")
    else
      Chef::Log.warn("pkg not in repo ? yum search returns #{cmd.stdout}")
    end
  end
end
```

however despite the fact that the pkg is in the repo the code does not work.

1) What am I doing wrong ?

2) Is there an easier way to do this ?

3) If the answer is "because your code is not running at run time how do I force it to run at Cf's run time ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not really how Chef works. You don't react to system state, you declared what it should be and then Chef enforces that. Way down in the depths it does the test-and-repair loop but high level, if the package should be installed then use a `package` resource. If you need to set up a specific repo first, we have the `yum_repository` resource. If this should be configurable per-host (or per-role, which is better) maybe use a node attribute to make the whole section conditional.

Comment: The issue here is that in a large enterprise you have no way to know in advance if the resources you need are going to be available to you. Hence the check. I could just run the Yum install but if it fails I will never know why as I wont have access to the console when it runs or the server logs.

Comment: You can Chef send a webhook or similar when there is an error along with details.

Comment: Why can't Chef just run simple ruby commands at the run phase ?

Comment: You could, but as you've noticed it's far from easy. Note how you're doing multiple rounds of string manipulation in both Bash and Ruby and it's still far from bulletproof. Hence my point that you are going about this incorrectly, you can read more at https://coderanger.net/thinking/